# It seems that I can't access the methods from class that I have created and had an implemented interface?

Tags: java, methods, interface

Why can't I access the methods from the class MyFixedSizeArrayList. Although I have implemented the interface of MyList and created the methods within the class MyFixedSizeArrayList

This is the interface

```
public interface MyList<E> {
public int getSize();
public void insert(E data) throws ListOverflowException;
public E getElement(E data) throws NoSuchElementException;
public boolean delete(E data); // returns false if the data is not deleted in the list
public boolean search(E data);
```

}

And I am trying to call insert method

```
public class MyFixedSizeArrayList implements MyList {
Object arraySize;

public MyFixedSizeArrayList(Object arraySize) {

}

public int getSize() {
    return (int) arraySize;
}

public void insert(Object data) throws ListOverflowException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input the data that you want to store: ");
    data = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("The "+ data + "has been stored");
}

public static void main(String[]args) throws ListOverflowException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<?> fixedArraySize = Arrays.asList(new MyFixedSizeArrayList(5));
    fixedArraySize.in
```

Comment: Why are you using `List<?>` and `Arrays.asList`? Since you wrote your own interface, you should use it! `MyList<Object> fixedArraySize = new MyFixedSizeArrayList<>(5);`

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is incorrect.

> List<?> fixedArraySize = Arrays.asList(new MyFixedSizeArrayList(5));

> fixedArraySize.in

**insert(Object data)** method of MyList will be visible only when you are accessing it from either MyFixedSizeArrayList or MyList.